# REACT - NATIVE "Build failed app:processReleaseResources"

Tags: android, react-native

Estoy generando una apk con react-native ya la corri en el emulador de Android e incluso en adb directamente en un dispositivo y funciona no genera ningun error.

pero al momento de ejecutar el comando:

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

para generar la apk.

me lanza el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje lo expresa claramente. `Failure to execute aapt`

**Respuesta corta:**

Hacer aapt ejecutable

**Respuesta Ligeramente más larga:**

1) Ejecutar `cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace`. El resultado mostrará la versión de la herramienta de compilación donde encontrará el aapt correcto para hacer el ejecutable y la ruta de acceso a él. por ejemplo: `Cannot run program "/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt" (in directory "/home/user/testproject/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android"): error=13, Permission denied`

2) Haga clic derecho en el archivo 'aapt', haga clic en los permisos, haga clic en la casilla de verificación marcada 'Ejecutar'

3) Corre `./gradlew clean &&  ./gradlew assembleDebug` o `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace` otra vez y creo que debería funcionar.

**Algo más que puedes verificar es:**

Entrar en la carpeta `node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android` y editar el archivo `build.gradle` con el que corresponde `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `minSdkVersion`, y `targetSdkVersionde` tus `{root}/android/app` nivel `build.gradle` versiones.

Un problema es una ruta de archivo larga. Durante la "compilación"

`react-native run-android`

Mira [esta información](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) puede ser útil.

Comment: no funciono aun genera el eror pero gracias por la ayuda

Comment: y ¿ como "Hacer aapt ejecutable" ? :-?